# How to create a NULL SET PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, set

I want to save a StringSET in the database. But it needs to be empty, to add stuff later. But what should I put in that "Type" column? When I try to put values for the SET it works, but as I said, it needs to be null. Thanks.

[image]
EDIT------------------------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the default values of that column to NULL first

[image: null values]

And make sure, Null checkbox already checked
[image: null]

Comment: I do that. But I aways get: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: see my edited post above, have you checked the null checkbox?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Mine is different than yours. I don't have this DAFAULTcolumn. I Updated the post so you can see how mine is.

Comment: hi, may I ask you, why do you use the "SET" type of the column?

Comment: I need to store a String Array actually. And that's the only type I found that could do it.

Comment: have you tried '' (empty string) instead of null ?, because I'm afraid that SET data type doesn't allow null, because it stores array value

Comment: It worked, thanks. But do you know if this empty string is filling the first "slot" of the set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100496/discussion-between-webster-and-cas).